# Fermionic partition function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions

When we calculate the fermionic partition function, we use $\newcommand{\ket}[1]{| #1 \rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\langle #1 |} \newcommand{\braket}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}$

$Z=tr(e^{-\beta H})=\int \bra{\bar \psi}e^{-\beta H}\ket{\psi} d\psi$

and in the bosonic case we use

$Z=tr(e^{-\beta H})=\int \bra{ \psi}e^{-\beta H}\ket{\psi} d\psi$

why $\braket{\bar \psi|\psi}=1$? Or following question, why is the resolution  of identity given by $\int \ket {\bar \psi}\bra{\psi}d\psi e^{-\bar \psi \psi}d\bar \psi=1$ instead of $\int \ket { \psi}\bra{\psi}d\psi e^{-\bar \psi \psi}d\bar \psi=1$?

I understand that there is something to do with the fermionic statistics, but I am not sure how we see it here.

Comment: The first equation should read $\int \langle - \psi | e^{-\beta H}|\psi\rangle d\psi^*d\psi$.

Answer (score 1):

These are coherent states, you need to take a look on what is  called "holomorphic representation of path integral". The coherent states which are the eigenvectors of the annihilation operator are not normalized. For the fermionic case you also need to use Grassmann variables.

Comment: By the way if you want a good book which rigourously explains this, take a look on the book " Path integrals in quantum mechanics" of Jean Zinn-Justin, this is an amazing introduction

Comment: Thanks. Are always eigenvalues of the form of coherent states?

Comment: I don't understand your question, if you're asking why we use coherent states, for me it's just because it simplifies things in some cases, for example if you try to solve the Harmonic oscillator with path integral, it is much more easy with coherent states.  You can also do that in the usual (x,p) representation of path integral but it's longer and more difficult.

Comment: I am not sure why can we use coherent states here, what ensures that we can write $\psi, \bar \psi$ as coherent states?

Comment: I mean this is by definition, the resolution of identity you gave are relations which are for ONLY for coherent states the exponential comes from the fact that coherent states are not normalized etc , i really advise you to take a look on the book i gave you, this is not so difficult you can prove that you have this expression for the closure relation and everything else